# Route binding with composite key

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I am trying to bind a model that has composite key. Take a look, at first place I define my route:

```
Route::get('laptop/{company}/{model}', 'TestController@test');
```

Now, I define as I want to be resolved:

```
$router->bind('laptop', function ($company, $model) {
    $laptop = ... select laptop where company=$company and ...;
    return $laptop;
});
```

Now, I see how I am injecting the class in order to get the laptop in the controller: function into to test the resolution:

```
function test(Laptop $laptop){
    return 'ok';
}
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

> BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 839:

I assume that the error is caused by `$router->bind('laptop'` because it should matches a unique placeholder in the url ("company" or "model"). In my case I get lost because I need to matches both at the same time.

> Note: I am not using db/eloquent layer. This problem is focused in the way on how to resolve route binding with multiples keys representing an unique object.

I am not sure if is it possible or if am I missing something. Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not support composite key in eloquent query.

You need to use query builder method of laravel to match against both values. ie: DB::select()->where()->where()->get();

Just put select and where conditions in above.

Comment: the problem is not in eloquent layer, the problem is in the route logic. Concretely how do you resolve a bind using two keys via route?

Comment: "I am trying to bind a model that has composite key. "    i thought as you said this that you are using composite key in a model this will not work. As laravel doesn't support it.

Comment: Yes, I am using models, but not in eloquent context

Comment: It is really rare when I use Eloquent. I prefer to manage the data on my own way, because it is cleaner, much easier to test and the code is more understandable and flexible, besides the great advantage of not having the limitations that Eloquent has.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind `$router->bind('laptop', ...);` then your route parameter should be `Route::get('{laptop}', ...);`. There is two possibility to query a laptop by `model` and `company` as you expected.

The safest way is query laptop on your controller:

```
Route::get('laptop/{company}/{model}', 'TestController@test');
```

In you `TestController.php`

```
function test(Laptop $laptop, $company, $model){
    return $laptop->whereCompany($company)->whereModel($model)->first();
}
```

Another solution is allow slashes on your route parameter:

```
Route::get('laptop/{laptop}', 'TestController@test')->where('laptop', , '(.*)?');
```

and your binding function could be:

```
$router->bind('laptop', function ($laptop) {
    $laptop  = explode('/', $laptop);
    $company = current($laptop);
    $model   = end($laptop);

    if ((count($laptop) === 2) && ($result = App\Laptop::whereCompany($company)->whereModel($model)->first()) {
        return $result;
    }

    return abort(404);
}
```